# Using USB to install Ubuntu

Tags: usb, downloads

I installed Ubuntu onto my hard drive (from this website), then I transferred it onto my USB flash drive.  When I try to boot it up it doesn't show up on my screen. What am I missing?

Comment: When you try to boot from USB what shows on your screen?

Comment: I get power options, "boot from USB" and "reset computer."  I'm running w10

Answer (score 0):

Try holding down shift and pressing the restart button at the same time. This will open up a BIOS menu, and within it there should be a setting to "boot from flash drive" instead of hard drive. Doing that should work.

Comment: Note that this only applies to Windows 8+

Comment: I use Windows 10

Comment: Then this should work fine for you.